Publish to web: report not eligible
We have a report that we can't publish to the web. The error says "Warning:  You can't create an embed code because the report is not eligible for use with Publish to web."
I think the problem is that some of the data sources in our semantic model can't be used with Publish to web, but all of the sources in the report itself look eligible to us.
Does anyone know if the limitation on data sources is applied at the semantic model level, or if it's applied on the report level?  Our data team has added lots of sources to our semantic model, and we don't want to remove the ineligible ones unless we have to.
Thank you,

Have you checked the admin setting in PBI? https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Contact-your-admin-to-enable-embed-code-creation/td-p/999592
